# What does cum.sums mean in R when running a probability simulation

Tags: probability

I'm running this simulation where you roll a die in R and record the result. Part of the code I got from my professor says 
cumulative.sums = cumsum(roll == 1)

I'm not exactly sure what this code means. and here's the result I got.
trial.num roll.result cumulative.sums proportion
[1,]         1           6               0  0.0000000
[2,]         2           3               0  0.0000000
[3,]         3           1               1  0.3333333
[4,]         4           3               1  0.2500000
[5,]         5           1               2  0.4000000
[6,]         6           3               2  0.3333333

Comment: No reaction to the answer below? Accepting it seems like a minimum...

Answer (score 1):

You can always google:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html

And this function is shown very clearly by its name - cumulative sum: It is summing all the elements in a vector, the argument of this function.

In your example the vector "roll==1" is extracting the indicator of each roll results equal to 1 as a vector, so essentially you are counting the number of 1's in the vector "roll".